# search all matching patterns in excel 2003 and replace

Tags: excel-2003

I am basically looking for an excel based formula that can look in the cell value and replace all instances of ;# with a space or "; ". For the start, I know search replace functionality, I know macros can do that, the challenge is that I can not use either of the two methods.

The data appears in the following format:

```
;#Business Mix;#Improve Productivity;#
;#Distribution;#Improve Productivity;#
;#Distribution;#Improve Productivity;#
;#Risk Selection;#Business Mix;#Improve Productivity;#
;#Risk Selection;#Business Mix;#Improve Productivity;#
;#Risk Selection;#Business Mix;#Improve Productivity;#
;#Distribution;#Improve Productivity;#
;#Distribution;#Improve Productivity;#
;#Distribution;#Improve Productivity;#
;#Distribution;#Improve Productivity;#
;#Distribution;#Improve Productivity;#
;#Distribution;#Improve Productivity;#
;#Distribution;#Improve Productivity;#
```

I am currently using the following formula to arrive at the solution but does not work perfectly:

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(REPLACE(VLOOKUP($D$2,all,3,FALSE),3,2,""),LEN(REPLACE(VLOOKUP(D2,all,3,FALSE),3,2,""))-2),FIND(";#",LEFT(REPLACE(VLOOKUP(D2,all,3,FALSE),3,2,""),LEN(REPLACE(VLOOKUP(D2,all,3,FALSE),3,2,""))-2),1),2,"; "),FIND(";#",REPLACE(LEFT(REPLACE(VLOOKUP(D2,all,3,FALSE),3,2,""),LEN(REPLACE(VLOOKUP(D2,all,3,FALSE),3,2,""))-2),FIND(";#",LEFT(REPLACE(VLOOKUP(D2,all,3,FALSE),3,2,""),LEN(REPLACE(VLOOKUP(D2,all,3,FALSE),3,2,""))-2),1),2,"; "),1),2,"; ")
```

all = named range

So we could have one item

```
;#Business Mix;#
```

or

```
;#Business Mix;#Improve Productivity;#
```

or more than two or three or four.

The end result should have only the texts separated by ; and if there is only one selection e.g. Business mix, if should have no ;.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [Text to Columns](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJmczgZ_Myo) with `#` as the delimiter. Stitch the columns back together, say in D1, with =CONCATENATE (say =E1&F1&G1...) copied down to suit, copy the results and Paste Special Values over the top, add

> =IF(RIGHT(D1,1)=";",LEFT(D1,LEN(D1)-1),D1)

in Row1 of a spare column and copy down to suit. Copy all and Paste Special Values over the top again. Delete excess.